# How exactly replace:true works with element directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following custom directive:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('smartWidget', function () {
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<div>This is the template</div>'
        }
    });
```

for the html:

```
<div id="center">
        <smart-widget class="orange">blah blah</smart-widget>
</div>
```

with the css:

```
.orange{
    background:orange;
}
```

What I don't understand is that, when I set `replace:true` the widget shows with the orange background, and with `replace:false` it does not. I expected this to work the other way around, as in:

- with **true**: `<div id="center"><div>This is the template</div><div>`
- and with **false**: `<div id="center"><div class="orange"><div>This is the template</div><div><div>`, but i am obviously wrong about this!

Can anyone shed light on this please?

Comment: With replace true it will copy over all the attribute of the source element (`<smart-widget class="orange">blah blah</smart-widget>`) to the template root so it becomes `<div class="orange">This is the template</div>` and based on your css rule it will apply when replace:true when it is false ofcourse you have an invalid html node So css rule wont apply. And you will see it getting applied if you use attribute restriction, i.e `<div smart-widget class="orange">blah blah</div>` and `replace:false` because div is a valid html node.

Comment: [read here](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/customdirectives/replace/)

Comment: By the way, [`replace` is deprecated...](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb)

Comment: Thanks, this all makes sense now! Would I be getting invalid HTML because Angular leaves the '<smart-widget></smart-widget>' tags in the  HTML with 'replace:false' and 'restrict:'E''? Also, is there a way/tool to see the final HTML output after Angular compiled all directives?

Comment: @Crocodile Just use inspector in your browser to see what it renders. But generally if you understand the idea of how the directive works you generally do not have to inspect the element to see how it will be rendered.

Comment: All crystal clear now, thanks!

Comment: @PSL i disagree attributes dont get replaced those are carried with the replacement, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @A.B Yes attributes gets carried over.. What i said was probably the rules wont apply properly across browsers.. But from your example i could see it working. So i dont know what the actual issue  is.. :)

Comment: @PSL yes that's sort of confusing if it is than OP has got other problem not this one :)

Comment: @PSL not much sportsmanship today? ;)

Comment: @A.B WHat was that? :/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have checked that attributes are also replaced?

if you set attributes on directive `<some-widget class="orange red">` that will be replaced with but attributes will remain there like `<div class="orange red">This is the template</div>`

Actually what happens is that all the attributes of the original DOM node are merged with those in the template's root node

For Instance **see below**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
        .directive('someWidget', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                template: '<div>This is the template</div>',
                link: function (scope, element) {
                 
                  
                }
            };
        });
```

```css
.orange{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="app">
    <some-widget class="orange red">
       
       
    </some-widget>
      </div>
```

**Update for Invalid Html issue**

w3c validation allows any data-* attributes, so you can make "Attribute" directives and use them with data-*

for instance

```
<div data-some-widget></div>
```

and restricting it to

```
 restrict: 'A'
```

Comment: I think we are mixing two different questions I submitted today, which are not exactly asking the same thing. In this case what I did not know that 1.) attributes are carried over and 2.) I missed that <some-widget class="orange red"> is invalid HTML and hence the class attribute is ignored, as I understand from PSL's answer in the comments. But your code explains 1.) so I accepted it. Thanks much appreciated.

Comment: My Pleasure @Crocodile i have edited the answer for invalid HTML issue :)

Comment: Yeah #2 css rule does not apply properly because the html tag `<some-widget` does not have any inherent display behaviour (probably initial). So i am actually wrong when i said `css rule does not apply` but it is actually that the invalid element does not really take any default width of height as it is not a defined block element and it contains a block element. That is why it does not work when you tried to apply background color.

Comment: In reality, wouldn't the browser just ignore and skip an invalid html markup and any associated css?